# how to set bootstrap modal as confirm dialog?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how to set bootstrap modal as confirm window i am try this code but it returns true when modal is open.

this code not work it allow to redirect. before show a modal.

bootstrap modal:

```
<a href="https/www.google.com" id="btn-confirm">Confirm</a>

<div id="deletemodel" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">  </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you really want to delete these record? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info deleteCancel">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteConfirm">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
var modalConfirm = function(callback){

 $("#btn-confirm").on("click", function(){
    $("#deletemodel").modal('show');
 });
$("#deletemodel .deleteConfirm").on("click", function(){
    callback(true);
    $("#deletemodel").modal('hide');
});
$("#deletemodel .deleteCancel").on("click", function(){
    callback(false);
    $("#deletemodel").modal('hide');
});

};
modalConfirm(function(confirm){ 
  if(confirm){      
    return true;
  }else{        
    return false;
  } 
});
</script>
```

anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You are 90% done. You got the basics but you are missing some pieces. First you can define the modal to reference it whenever you need it (HTML file). Then on your script whenever you need it, you can set the "this.modal = <referenceToYourHTML>". Note that you will need to define the modalView, and the reference. Hope this helps you figuring things out.

Answer (score 0):

Just change a couple lines in your JS :

```
$('#btn-confirm').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//     <--- This line.
    $('#deletemodel').modal('show');
});
```

`e` is the click event.
`preventDefault` tells the browser not to follow the HTML default behavior (which usually prepends to the JS behavior).

```
$('#deletemodel .deleteCancel').on('click', function() {
    location.href = 'https://google.com'
});
```

Comment: sorry, it works but after click modal deleteConfirm button it will not redirect.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you have to manually redirect using `location.href = "https://google.com"`. Editing the answer... Done.